# C# - Excel: Deleting an entire row in excel, with a particular value at the first column of the row to be deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-web-api, delete-row

I am creating a web application using an excel file. If the excel file has m rows and n columns, and I have to delete the entire row if the value of cell in column A of the row is a string 'str'.

I tried various methods. The one I am stuck with right now deletes more than half of the existing elements. I'm working with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. I would like to know why that happens and a solution for the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
public void DeleteRow(int m, string str)
    {
        for (int rCnt = 2; rCnt <= m; rCnt++)
        {
             if((ws.Cells[rCnt, 1]).ToString().Contains(str))
             {
                ((Range)ws.Rows[rCnt]).Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);
             }
        }
        wb.Save();//save the workbook
        wb.Close(false, "", false);//close the workbook
    }
}
```

I even tried using:

```
((Range)ws.Rows[rCnt]).EntireRow.Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);
```

instead of:

```
((Range)ws.Rows[rCnt]).Delete(XlDirection.xlUp);
```

Comment: what is meant by "... deletes more that half of the existing elements..."? Does "elements" mean "rows" here? Is it deleting rows that should not be deleted? Missing rows that should be deleted?

Comment: Yes, it's deleting rows that shouldn't be deleted. Say there are 382 rows. When I try deleting one row, it deletes 194 rows! And shows the rest 188 rows only.

Comment: Please add a print statement of `ws.Cells[rCnt, 1]`

Comment: Yes, I did. Shouldn't it display the print output in console under debug mode? I couldn't see the output. I'm sort of a beginner.

Comment: @Tarik and @ArcherBird I think the problem is with the 'if case'. I don't think it's accepting the value in the cell. Do you guys know how to get the exact value? I have changed the code abit. Right now no rows are getting deleted. It seems like it isn't going inside the if case because the value accepted by ```(ws.Cells[rCnt,1]).ToString()``` isn't the same as the value in the cell.

Comment: `I'm working with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.` you can't use Excel on a web server. First of all, you'd have to buy a separate license for *every* end user. Second, each request would end up starting a *new* Excel instance on the server, and probably leave it running. You're closing the workbook, but are you also closing the *application* ?. The server could exhaust its memory after a few requests.

Comment: Use a library like Epplus to create and edit real Excel (xlsx) files instead.

Comment: try accessing the `.Value2` property of the range for your conditional check:
`ws.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value2.ToString().Contains(str)`. But also note that if you deleted while looping downward like this, you will run into the problem that Tarik points out. The smartest way to do this is to probably loop through and build a disjointed range (using the `Excel.Application.Union(...)` method) and then call delete on that single range object. It will certainly be more performant if you are deleted many rows

Comment: Try using `.Value.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

Go bottom up:

```
for (int rCnt = m; rCnt >= 2; rCnt--)
```

This will avoid deleting the wrong rows as rows shift after deletion.

Comment: @ArcherBird Fixed. Thanks for pointing out my omission.

Comment: I have written many loops that execute exactly once... some that will never execute. Lol! I think your idea likely answers this question.

Comment: @Tarik I tried that too. For this case if it's 382 rows initially, after trying to delete a row, it deletes 343 rows.